# I am trying to integrate Dropbox into my website. What does "curl" mean and how do I use it?

Tags: javascript, html, curl, dropbox

I went on the /list_folders method in the HTTP Developers guide (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) and it has "curl" as the example of how to use it. How do I put this in my HTML/JS code to pull in the folders? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try *googling curl*? Or hovering over the `curl` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the reference for the JavaScript Dropbox library [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) which will guide you through creating a front-end website that utilizes the API. CURL is a very popular command line script used to transfer data over many supported protocols, but not something you can use from the browser.

More on the Dropbox API, [this](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/basic/index.html) example Javascript script will show you how to list files.

The partial documentation can be found [here](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/).